# Something strange about Red-Black Tree Delete in Introduction to Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

In the Introduction to Algorithms 3rd edition, page 329, Figure 13.7 shows us about the 4 deletion cases.

[image]
<sub>(source: [quoracdn.net](http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-ad5e030dca260dcaf853e658f8555dd3?convert_to_webp=true))</sub>

But I have a problem: in that figure, all the node of `x` is BLACK and it's not nil. But I have tested many cases and it turns out that `x` must be either a RED node or nil, for the reason:

> If the z has less then 2 children, then x must be a RED node or nil because z's black height must be 1.
>
> If the z has 2 children, the x must be a RED node or nil because y is the successor of z and y's left child must be nil, then y's black height must be 1.

Am I wrong? Or is there anything that I has ignored? Hope someone can help me.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

What is z? It is not marked on any of the 4 cases. Do you mean w the sibling node?

To my mind, x is either null (and that is valid, you have just deleted it) or it is black and the node you have deleted is further down either x's left child tree or x's right child tree.

Note also before the FIXUP routine is called, various other cases are called.
If the node to deleted has 0 children and is Red => just delete it. It is a leaf node. It is still a red-black tree.
If the node to deleted has 1 child => The node is black and child red. No other possibilities can occur as they break the Red-Black tree rules. Delete the node and replace with the Child. The Child is now black. It is still a Red-Black tree.
If the node to be deleted has 2 children => Find the inorder Successor or Predecessor. Swap nodes to be deleted **BUT NOT THE COLOURS**. The inorder Successor or Predecessor will always be a node with 0 or 1 children. Now you just need to delete that which reduces to the 2 cases above.
So what is left to do?
The difficult case: 0 children and the node is Black.

In the diagrams above, case 2 is the start case and the sibling left and right children are nil. x no longer exists but w does and is black

To my mind, you need to find out in your code why x is red. It should never be red. If it is, the preamble code before the fixup code is not working and the fixup code is only called when the node to be deleted is black and with no children.